# launching deluge with different user creditential

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, user, deluge

i want to launch deluge from a different user which has ther permission to write to specific folder where deluge will download.

so i `su` to that username `media` then run this from terminal `/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop`

but this gives this error:

```
     $ /usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 1: [Desktop: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 58: Client: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 59: de: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 60: klient: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 63: BitTorrent: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 64: Client: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 65: Client: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 66: Client: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 67: de: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 68: klient: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 69: Bezeroa: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 71: BitTorrent: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 72: de: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 73: klijent: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 74: kliens: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 75: BitTorrent: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 76: クライアント: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 77: კლიენტი: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 78: klientas: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 79: klients: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 80: клиент: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 81: BitTorrent: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 83: BitTorrent: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 84: bittorrent: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 85: BitTorrent: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 86: BitTorrent: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 87: клиент: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 88: අනුග්‍රාහකයා: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 89: klient: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 90: za: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 92: İstemcisi: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 93: BitTorrent: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 94: 用戶端: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 95: X-GNOME-FullName=Deluge: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 96: X-GNOME-FullName[ca]=Client: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 97: X-GNOME-FullName[cs]=BitTorrent: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 98: X-GNOME-FullName[da]=Deluge: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 99: X-GNOME-FullName[de]=Deluge: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 100: X-GNOME-FullName[el]=Πελάτης: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 101: X-GNOME-FullName[en_AU]=Deluge: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 102: X-GNOME-FullName[en_CA]=Deluge: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 103: X-GNOME-FullName[en_GB]=Deluge: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 104: X-GNOME-FullName[es]=Cliente: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 105: X-GNOME-FullName[et]=Deluge: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 106: X-GNOME-FullName[eu]=Deluge: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 107: X-GNOME-FullName[fi]=Deluge-BitTorrent-sovellus: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 108: X-GNOME-FullName[fr]=Client: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 109: X-GNOME-FullName[gl]=Cliente: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 110: X-GNOME-FullName[hr]=Deluge: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 111: X-GNOME-FullName[hu]=Deluge: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 112: X-GNOME-FullName[it]=Client: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 113: X-GNOME-FullName[ka]=BitTorrent: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 114: X-GNOME-FullName[lt]=Deluge: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 115: X-GNOME-FullName[lv]=Deluge: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 116: X-GNOME-FullName[mk]=Deluge: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 117: X-GNOME-FullName[ms]=Klien: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 118: X-GNOME-FullName[nn]=Deluge: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 119: X-GNOME-FullName[oc]=Client: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 120: X-GNOME-FullName[pt]=Deluge: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 121: X-GNOME-FullName[pt_BR]=Cliente: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 122: X-GNOME-FullName[ro]=Client: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 123: X-GNOME-FullName[ru]=BitTorrent: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 124: X-GNOME-FullName[si]=Deluge: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 125: X-GNOME-FullName[sk]=Deluge: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 126: X-GNOME-FullName[sl]=Deluge,: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 127: X-GNOME-FullName[sv]=BitTorrent-klienten: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 128: X-GNOME-FullName[tr]=Deluge: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 129: X-GNOME-FullName[uk]=BitTorrent: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 130: X-GNOME-FullName[zh_TW]=Deluge: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 131: and: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 132: i: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 133: a: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 134: og: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 135: über: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 136: και: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 137: and: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 138: and: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 139: and: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 140: y: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 141: alla: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 142: eta: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 143: ja: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 144: et: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 145: e: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 146: i: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 147: letöltése: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 148: e: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 149: და: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 150: ir: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 151: un: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 152: и: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 153: turun: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 154: ned: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 155: e: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 156: e: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 157: e: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 158: și: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 159: и: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 160: හරහා: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 161: a: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 162: in: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 163: och: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 164: üzerinden: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 165: та: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 166: BitTorrent: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 168: fg: no job control
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 172: FileTransfer: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 172: P2P: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 172: GTK: command not found
/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop: line 175: x-scheme-handler/magnet: No such file or directory
```

am i launching it wrong?

then i tried like this `deluge-gtk` but that too errored

```
media@raspberrypi:/usr/share/applications $ deluge-gtk %U
Client is not authorized to connect to Server/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/ui/gtkui/queuedtorrents.py:60: Warning: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
  "glade/queuedtorrents.glade"))
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/ui/gtkui/queuedtorrents.py:60: Warning: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
  "glade/queuedtorrents.glade"))
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/ui/gtkui/queuedtorrents.py:60: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  "glade/queuedtorrents.glade"))
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/ui/gtkui/queuedtorrents.py:60: Warning: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  "glade/queuedtorrents.glade"))
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/ui/gtkui/queuedtorrents.py:76: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  gtk.TreeViewColumn(_("Torrent"), gtk.CellRendererText(), text=0))
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/ui/gtkui/queuedtorrents.py:76: Warning: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  gtk.TreeViewColumn(_("Torrent"), gtk.CellRendererText(), text=0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/deluge-gtk", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('deluge==1.3.10', 'gui_scripts', 'deluge-gtk')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/ui/gtkui/gtkui.py", line 122, in start
    Gtk().start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/ui/gtkui/gtkui.py", line 119, in start
    GtkUI(self.args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/ui/gtkui/gtkui.py", line 240, in __init__
    self.ipcinterface = IPCInterface(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/ui/gtkui/ipcinterface.py", line 92, in __init__
    os.makedirs(ipc_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/pi/.config/deluge/ipc'
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to run the deluge gui or run the deluge daemon for web access? (also, running `/usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop` definitely won't run it, because a .desktop file is basically desktop icon that LXDE reads to run a program.)

Comment: Just deluge gui